# C++ runtime error: addition of unsigned offset?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I wrote the following to check if text is palindrome, I run it on leetcode and I am getting errors:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        int l=0,r=s.length()-1;
        while(l<r)
        {
            while (!isalpha(s[r]))
            {
                --r;
            }
            while (!isalpha(s[l]))
            {
                ++l;
            }
            if (tolower(s[r])!=tolower(s[l]))
                return false;
            --r;
            ++l;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

> Line 1061: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to
> 0x7ffc7cc10880 overflowed to 0x7ffc7cc1087f (basic_string.h) SUMMARY:
> UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:1070:9

what's the problem with my code?

Comment: You're going out of bounds here: `while (!isalpha(s[r]))` and here `while (!isalpha(s[l]))`. You should add some checks like `while (l < s.length() && !isalpha(s[l]))`

Comment: Input such as `""` or `"..."` would be problematic.

Comment: As the runtime error declared, you are going to reach out of the string's limits.
You should check that you are not going to pass those limits in each of your `while` loops.

Answer (score 3):

You're going out of bounds here:

```
while (!isalpha(s[r]))
```

and here

```
while (!isalpha(s[l]))
```

`r` can became negative and `l` can become `>= s.length()`.

You should add some checks like

```
while (l < r && !isalpha(s[r]))
```

and

```
while (l < r && !isalpha(s[l]))
```

The same problem in this line

```
if (tolower(s[r])!=tolower(s[l]))
```

This should be

```
if (l < r && tolower(s[r])!=tolower(s[l]))
```

### Different approach (C++20)

A different approach is to erase all non-alpha characters from `s` with

```
std::erase_if(s, [](char c) { return !isalpha(c); });
```

and remove the inner while loops.

Comment: but the checks will make the solution not valid if input was ","

Comment: @calc But without the checks your code causes undefined behavior. What value do you expect from `s[-1]` or `s[s.length() + 2]`? That's exactly the problem in your code for input like `s = "123"`, `s = ""` or `s = ","`. You're going out of bounds because you don't check the bounds. Is `","` a palindrome or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were very close to the solution. The pitfall here are that:

- you are modifying the loop control variable more than once in the loop
- (as consequence) you are using the loop control variable after changing their values without further checks.

The easy way to fix this kind of issue is to do one single action for every iteration. you can achieve this just using "else".

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        int l=0,r=s.length()-1;
        while(l<r)
        {
            if(!isalpha(s[r]))
            {
                --r;
            }
            else if(!isalpha(s[l]))
            {
                ++l;
            }
            else if (tolower(s[r])!=tolower(s[l]))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                --r;
                ++l;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar modified approach, where you continue the loop whenever you encounter any non-alphanumeric char solves the problem.
Here:

```
bool isPalindrome(string s) {    
    int start=0,end=s.length()-1;
    
    while(start<=end){
        if(!isalpha(s[start])  && !isdigit(s[start])){
            start++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(!isalpha(s[end]) && !isdigit(s[end])){
            end--;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(tolower(s[start])!=tolower(s[end])){
            return false;
        }
        
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are going out of bounds in some cases. so you can attempt the below code to have no error and no memory leakage.

```
bool isPalindrome(string s) {
  string a="";
  for(int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++)
  {
   if(s[i]>=65 && s[i]<=90)
        a+=(s[i]+32);
        else if(s[i]>=97 && s[i]<=122)
        a+=s[i];
        else if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')
        a+=s[i];
    }
    int start=0, end=a.length()-1;
    while(start<end)
    {
        if(a[start++]!=a[end--])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Spaghetti code! You overdo it!

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, you are running out of bonds.
Here is a simplified solution that will not run out of bonds and also is free of if-then-else spaghetti code:

```
bool IsPalindrome(const char *s)
{
    int forward, totLen, halfLen, backward;

    totLen = (int)strlen(s);    // Total length
    halfLen = totLen / 2;       // Half the length, if totLen is odd, will ignore the character in the middle

    for (forward = 0; forward < halfLen; forward++) // Index from front of string
    {
        backward = totLen - (forward + 1);          // Corresponding index from back of string
        if (s[forward] != s[backward])
            return false;                           // Not a palindrome
    }
    return true;    // Got one!
}
```